# Recaptcha form validation fails in different page where I haven't added the recaptcha

Tags: angularjs

We have multiple pages in sites using angular JS. I added this recaptcha in first page, first page works fine, come back with success response and goes to second page. In the second page, I haven't added this recaptcha at all, but it says validation fails in the second page. When I debug, the form validation is set to false and it mentions the page cannot be saved. The problem is that we can't get into the next page from second page. We use angular JS 1.2.28

I have done server side validation using apex class, it does validate in first page and goes to second page. However, second page gets blocked by missing fields in the form. Here is the code I added in angular JS for first page if that helps.  I have a screenshot of the form where it says invalid. I will try to attach that too. I am stuck with this issue for many days now.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 form-group">
            <div vc-recaptcha ng-required="true" name="recaptcha" ng-model="applicant.myRecaptchaResponse" key="'xxxxxxx'">
            </div>
            <div ng-if="form.showAllErrors">
                <p class="help-block text-danger" ng-if="form.recaptcha.$invalid">Please check this option.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If the form is invalid on the second 'page', then you need the find the formcontrol that is invalid. Might have nothing to do with that recaptcha.

Comment: Can you show us some code so that we can reproduce your problem and help you solve it?

Comment: I have added the code I added in first page.